# Multiple functions binding to checked event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

It is possible to bind multiple functions to checked event in Knockout like this code snippet?

**Code snippet:**

```
<input type="radio" name="requestType" data-bind="value: id, checked: checkedRequestTypeId, isRequestTypeIdChecked" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = function() {
        //...
        checkedRequestTypeId  = ko.observable();
        isRequestTypeIdChecked = function(){
            //some logic inside
        }
        //...
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
</script>
```

Or I can bind only one function and call two different functions inside this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that at your situation you can use subscribe function to follow checkedRequestTypeId:

```
<input type="radio" name="requestType" data-bind="value: id, checked: checkedRequestTypeId, isRequestTypeIdChecked" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = function() {
        //...
        checkedRequestTypeId  = ko.observable();

        this.checkedRequestTypeId.subscribe(function(){
            //some logic inside
        }

    };

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
</script>
```

I hope that my answer can help to you.
More details you can read here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot, not with the built-in `checked` binding. You could write a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) if you really want one (write one that re-uses or forks [the built in binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/checked.js)), but there's an easier way to get something similar.

I suggest using a writeable computed. You would need that anyways, to encapsulate the two-way binding bit. Put differently, notidce that you can change `checkedRequestTypeId` and `isRequestTypeIdChecked` both programmatically, and you have to decide whether the checkbox should be checked or not in those circumstances.

You have not provided details on logic for the edge cases, but here's an example to get you started:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.checkedRequestTypeId = ko.observable(false);
  self.isRequestTypeIdChecked = ko.observable(true);
  
  self.requestTypeCheckedness = ko.computed({
    read: function() { 
      return self.checkedRequestTypeId() && self.isRequestTypeIdChecked()
        ? "1"
        : "2";
    },
    write: function(newVal) {
      self.checkedRequestTypeId(newVal === "1");
      self.isRequestTypeIdChecked(newVal === "1");
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="requestType" value="1" data-bind="checked: requestTypeCheckedness" /> 1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="requestType" value="2" data-bind="checked: requestTypeCheckedness" /> 2

<hr>
Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

PS. I also support [Stanislav Machel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40989884/419956) as a good, alternative way to solve this. Whichever is best depends on context, really.